# angular material 2 sidenav error: .open is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-material

The code in the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Y5R7WqliF9M98g7LY0x8?p=preview) works fine but it doesn't work on my computer. when i click the open side nav button, i see the error '.open is not a function' [screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3vKq.png)

```
//app.component.html
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container">
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav class="example-sidenav">
      Jolly good!
    </mat-sidenav>

    <div class="example-sidenav-content">
      <button type="button" mat-button (click)="sidenav.open()">
        Open sidenav
      </button>
    </div>

  </mat-sidenav-container>
//app.component.ts
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}

//app.component.css
.example-container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }

  .example-sidenav-content {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .example-sidenav {
    padding: 20px;
  }
```

Comment: This error also may appear if you have not given your `mat-sidenav` element a name to be referenced by, like: `#sidenav`. I see that your example has this, but it is common to get that messed up too. If you get the spelling wrong when calling open referencing that template variable `sidenav.open()`, the spelling as well with ensuring the variable is set are two things to check when getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `MatSidenavModule` in your imports section of `@NgModule`.

I reproduced your error. See this link:https://plnkr.co/edit/HalfBwhQ0atvlhmCN3An?p=preview
In this there is no `MatSidenavModule` in `@NgModule`.

Please refer:https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/api